# How to plot the model output?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, machine-learning

My 'z_sample' should be of shape (1, 10) according to the model, but it takes shape (1, 2) and throws the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "dense_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1of input shape to have value 10, but received input with shape (1, 2)
```

As far as I understand, the error lies in this snippet:

```
for i, yi in enumerate(grid_y):
    for j, xi in enumerate(grid_x):
      z_sample = np.array([[xi, yi]])
      x_decoded = vae_decoder(z_sample)
```

How can I write it down correctly to plot the model output?
Here is the full plot function:

```
def plot_latent_space(n=30, figsize=15):
  digit_size = 28
  scale = 1.5
  figure = np.zeros((digit_size * n, digit_size * n))

  grid_x = np.linspace(-scale, scale, n)
  grid_y = np.linspace(-scale, scale, n)[::-1]

  for i, yi in enumerate(grid_y):
    for j, xi in enumerate(grid_x):
      z_sample = np.array([[xi, yi]])
      x_decoded = vae_decoder(z_sample)
      digit = tf.reshape(x_decoded[0], shape=(digit_size, digit_size))
      figure[
             i * digit_size : (i + 1) * digit_size,
             j * digit_size : (j + 1) * digit_size,
      ] = digit

  plt.figure(figsize=(figsize, figsize))
  start_range = digit_size // 2
  end_range = n * digit_size + start_range
  pixel_range = np.arange(start_range, end_range, digit_size)
  sample_range_x = np.round(grid_x, 1)
  sample_range_y = np.round(grid_y, 1)
  plt.xticks(pixel_range, sample_range_x)
  plt.yticks(pixel_range, sample_range_y)
  plt.xlabel("z[0]")
  plt.ylabel("z[1]")
  plt.imshow(figure, cmap="Greys_r")
  plt.show()
```

The model output is as follows:

```
Model: "encoder"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_4 (InputLayer)           [(None, 28, 28, 1)]  0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_6 (Conv2D)              multiple             156         ['input_4[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_6 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 14, 14, 6)   0           ['conv2d_6[1][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_7 (Conv2D)              (None, 10, 10, 16)   2416        ['max_pooling2d_6[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 max_pooling2d_7 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 5, 5, 16)    0           ['conv2d_7[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 flatten_3 (Flatten)            (None, 400)          0           ['max_pooling2d_7[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 dense_6 (Dense)                (None, 20)           8020        ['flatten_3[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 tf.split_2 (TFOpLambda)        [(None, 10),         0           ['dense_6[0][0]']                
                                 (None, 10)]                                                      
                                                                                                  
 tf.math.multiply_4 (TFOpLambda  (None, 10)          0           ['tf.split_2[0][1]']             
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 tf.compat.v1.shape_2 (TFOpLamb  (2,)                0           ['tf.split_2[0][0]']             
 da)                                                                                              
                                                                                                  
 tf.math.exp_2 (TFOpLambda)     (None, 10)           0           ['tf.math.multiply_4[0][0]']     
                                                                                                  
 tf.random.normal_2 (TFOpLambda  (None, 10)          0           ['tf.compat.v1.shape_2[0][0]']   
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 tf.math.multiply_5 (TFOpLambda  (None, 10)          0           ['tf.math.exp_2[0][0]',          
 )                                                                'tf.random.normal_2[0][0]']     
                                                                                                  
 tf.__operators__.add_2 (TFOpLa  (None, 10)          0           ['tf.split_2[0][0]',             
 mbda)                                                            'tf.math.multiply_5[0][0]']     
                                                                                                  
 dense_7 (Dense)                (None, 400)          4400        ['tf.__operators__.add_2[0][0]'] 
                                                                                                  
 reshape_3 (Reshape)            (None, 5, 5, 16)     0           ['dense_7[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 up_sampling2d_6 (UpSampling2D)  multiple            0           ['reshape_3[0][0]',              
                                                                  'conv2d_transpose_8[0][0]']     
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_transpose_8 (Conv2DTran  (None, 14, 14, 16)  6416        ['up_sampling2d_6[0][0]']        
 spose)                                                                                           
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_transpose_9 (Conv2DTran  (None, 28, 28, 6)   2406        ['up_sampling2d_6[1][0]']        
 spose)                                                                                           
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_transpose_10 (Conv2DTra  (None, 28, 28, 1)   55          ['conv2d_transpose_9[0][0]']     
 nspose)                                                                                          
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 23,869
Trainable params: 23,869
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: Why are you giving input of shape (1, 2) if you know that is not correct and it should be (1, 10)?

Comment: @Dr. Snoopy My initial try was with latent_dim=2 which was ok with this plot, but for higher latent dimension it is challenging for me to visualize it.

Comment: That does not really answer my question, giving the wrong input will produce an error, whatever you can visualize it or not is a different problem.

Comment: @Dr. Snoopy I have added the model output. Could you show me the wrong input, please